# Using the "Post / Redirect / Get" pattern in Lynx doesn't work because Lynx doesn't redirect

Tags: http, redirect, post-redirect-get, lynx

After doing a POST to save a page, I return with a redirect the GET page (ie. the ["Post/Redirect/Get"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern).

This works fine in all the "mainstream" (and some not-so-mainstream) browsers I tested, *except* for lynx & derivatives (links, elinks); they do the POST, I return a 303, and the browser just stays on the other page (it doesn't load the URL in the GET response).

I tried using a 302 & 301, and setting the `Cache-Control` header to `no-cache`; which made no difference.

Example response from my server after doing a `POST /`:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Sat, 10 Jan 2015 17:32:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://localhost/
Connection: keep-alive
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

I happen to be using Sinatra, so here's an example application in Sinatra which demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    "<form method='post'>#{Time.now.to_s}<textarea name='test'></textarea><button>POST</button></form>"
end
post('/') { redirect '/' }
```

Is this by design? Or a different reading of the HTTP spec than most other browsers? How do I "force" lynx to do the redirect and GET the page again?

Tested in:

```
[~]% lynx --version
Lynx Version 2.8.8rel.1 (14 Feb 2014)
libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k, ncurses 5.9.20110404

[~]% links -version
Links 2.9

[~]% elinks -version
ELinks 0.13.GIT a3751107033599b835eaafa61177c8d4dda4b7ef-dirty
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time to step through the lynx source right now, but this behavior could be either a bug or a feature.  The [2.8.8rel.1 source](http://lynx.isc.org/current/lynx2.8.8rel.1.tar.bz2), in WWW/Library/Implementation/HTTP.c, method `HTLoadHTTP`, starting about line 1988, may hold some answers.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks ... I did some digging and `printf`-debugging, but it's not completely obvious to me why we get this behaviour. This *only* seems to occur if the URL is the same (so I can work around it, see my "answer") ...

Answer (score 2):

This problem only seems to occur if we're redirecting to the same URL. So if `POST /page` does a redirect with `Location: /page` (same URL, but a GET) `lynx` decides to just not do anything...

I worked around this by using:

```
<form method='post' class="markdown" action="?s=t">
```

The `s` parameter does nothing, but now we do `POST /page?s=t` and redirect to `Location: /page`, which is different enough...

I have no idea if this is a bug or feature in Lynx...

Comment: Is there a work-around that doesn't involve modifying the form page?